# Saving then loading a `tibble` causes it to be not recognised by S4 methods

Tags: r, tibble, r-s4, rdata

I have an obscure problem in R that involves the S4 class system.

First I create a tibble and save it:

```r
df = tibble::tibble(a=1:5, b=2:6)
save(df, file="foo.Rdata")
```

Next, I close the R session, and start a new one (which for some reason matters).

Then, I define an S4 method that dispatches on a `data.frame` (which a `tibble` is a subclass of):

```
setGeneric("sumTheColumns", function(target){    
  standardGeneric("sumTheColumns")    
})    
setMethod("sumTheColumns", signature(target="data.frame"), function(target){    
    colSums(target)    
})    
     
load("foo.Rdata")    
print(df)    
print(class(df))    
print(showMethods(sumTheColumns))    
sumTheColumns(df)
```

From this, R outputs:

```
[1] "sumTheColumns"
  a b
1 1 2
2 2 3
3 3 4
4 4 5
5 5 6
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
Function: sumTheColumns (package .GlobalEnv)
target="data.frame"

Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘sumTheColumns’ for signature ‘"tbl_df"’
Calls: sumTheColumns -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

So as you can see, the `tibble` is being saved and loaded correct, and it retains its classes, however it no longer dispatches correctly. Interestingly, if you define and call these same methods in the first R session where we create `df`, these dispatch correctly.

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

In case this is an OS-specific bug, here is some output from `sessionInfo`:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)
Platform: x86_64-conda-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 21.04
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare the `loadedNamespaces()` entries in the two situations.  I see

```r
> loadedNamespaces()
[1] "compiler"  "graphics"  "utils"     "grDevices" "stats"     "datasets"  "methods"   "base"
```

in a clean new session, but after creating `df`, it grows to

```r
> loadedNamespaces()
 [1] "compiler"  "magrittr"  "ellipsis"  "graphics"  "pillar"    "glue"      "utils"    
 [8] "tibble"    "grDevices" "crayon"    "stats"     "utf8"      "fansi"     "datasets" 
[15] "vctrs"     "methods"   "lifecycle" "pkgconfig" "rlang"     "base"
```

So one of those new packages fixes the issue.  I'd guess it's `tibble` itself, and indeed I see the error in the new session, but not after I run `loadNamespace("tibble")` (which gets everything in the second list).  So a solution is:

To get your dataframe methods to work on tibbles, you could run

```
loadNamespace("tibble")
```

before calling them.  You would want to do this if you intend to treat tibbles as tibbles in other places, e.g. to get them to print the way tibbles print.

Alternatively, if you just want your code to work on tibbles as if they were dataframes, you could do what the `tibble` package does, and run

```
methods::setOldClass(c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

That won't load any packages, but it will tell the S4 system that tibbles inherit from dataframes.

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you, I didn't think to check `loadedNamespaces()`. It might be worth emphasising that simply running `loadNamespace("tibble")` at any point in the second script solves the problem.

Comment: I've made that more explicit now.

Comment: ... and added a lightweight solution:  tell S4 that tibbles inherit from dataframes, without loading all the other tibble support code.